# Getting Error in Library inclusion in Codeigniter controller

Tags: codeigniter, mpdf

When i run my aaplication in external server i get eror ,
`Message: Login::include_once(application/third_party/mpdf/mpdf.php) [function.Login-include-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory`.
The same application was running perfect in local server. Can anyone please suggest what could be wrong with it. My controller function ,

```
function pdfapp()   //for test  run individually
{
$this->load->model('Registration_model');
$appno='4/SCSELB/2013/KL01';
$data['table']  = $this->Registration_model->getall_app($appno);
$data['own_land']   = $this->Registration_model->get_ownland($appno);
$data['loan_data']  = $this->Registration_model->getloan_data($appno);
$apppdf='4_SCSELB_2013_KL01';
$data['apppdf']=$apppdf;
$pdfFilePath = FCPATH."reports/application/$apppdf.pdf";
if (file_exists($pdfFilePath) == FALSE)
{
    ini_set('memory_limit','32M'); 
    $html = $this->load->view('pdf_report2', $data, true);  
    include_once APPPATH.'third_party/mpdf/mpdf.php';
    $mpdf=new mPDF('c'); 
    $mpdf->SetFooter('           copyright@ KSDC'.'|{PAGENO}|'.'Applied on '.date('d-M-Y H.i.s')); 
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
    $mpdf->Output($pdfFilePath, 'F'); 
}                   
 $this->load->view('pdf_report2',$data);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting is of a file not existing, Did you you debug this line ?

```
     APPPATH.'third_party/mpdf/mpdf.php'; ?
```

what path do you get if you var_dump it?

Comment: Actually it worked fine in local WAMP server. The problem occured when i uploaded and executed it in remote lampp sever. Will that cause any difference , of same path being in WAMP & LAMPP??

Comment: APPPATH is defined in the index.php file:

` define('APPPATH', $application_folder.'/');`

(unless you changed that).

I would still debug it to see what output you're getting.
It looks like it should work but obviously it doesn't.